# I have tried nested function and I am not getting the expected output

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried working out nested function. But I am not getting the expected output.

```
def rectangle(x):
    def breadth():
        # nonlocal z
        z = 2 * 3
        return z
    breadth()

    area = x * breadth()
    print(area)

x = int(input("Enter the value x : "))
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what result are you getting? Also, I don't see how you are calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

Your have to call the **rectangle** function and also remove the **breadth()** call before area calculation:

```
def rectangle(x):
    def breadth():
        # nonlocal z
        z = 2 * 3
        return z
    area = x * breadth()
    print(area)

x = int(input("Enter the value x : "))
rectangle(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function NumberThirtyTwo(){
           var i, j, k;
         for(i=65; i<=69; i++){
               var str = ''
            for(j=69; j>=i; j--){
                 str += '  '
           
           }
            for(k=65; k<=i; k++){
                str += (String.fromCharCode(k)+ '');
                       n = k - 1;
            for(m=65; m<i; m++)
                str +=(String.fromCharCode(--n)+ '');
            }
            console.log(str)
        }
    }
```

NumberThirtyTwo()